# Character replacement for Control Sequence Introducer Character in VB? Chr(155)

Tags: vb.net, replace

I have tried all day to replace this character I have in a string which has characters in it... and after googling, I found is called a "Control Sequence Introducer".

It looks like the hex code is 9B and the ASCII code is 155. (I think, from what I've read).

The string comes from a file which I read in, I have some null characters to replace, which is working fine, but just after that I've been working to remove this wierd character.

In notepad++ when I do show all symbols, it looks like this: [image: Conrol Sequence Introducer Character]

**I tried the following**:

`strLine = strLine.Replace(Chr(155), " ")`

`strLine = Replace(strLine , "9B", " ")`

`strLine = Replace(strLine , "&#x9B", " ")`

`strLine = Replace(strLine , Chr(155), " ")`

`strLine= Regex.Replace(strLine, "\c@", " ")`

`strLine= Regex.Replace(strLine, "\c_", " ")`

`strLine= Regex.Replace(strLine, "\c", " ")`

`strLine= Regex.Replace(strLine, "\cA", " ")`

`strLine= Regex.Replace(strLine, "\cZ", " ")`

I found a good section in wikipedia

[Control Sequence Introducer Character ANSI Control Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences)

With everything going on in that, perhaps I have the wrong hex code?
Does anybody know how to replace this character? I have googled this for awhile now and it's elusive to me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I did find it finally, using regex and the hex code!

strLine = Regex.Replace(strLine, "\x9B", " ")